# Anaconda application is not opening in my PC

Tags: python, anaconda

After successfully downloading and installing Anaconda on my PC, but I'm not able to open it. I tried uninstalling it and again installing it but it was of no use. I also tried adding the path to the environment but it was not helpful. I faced a similar problem while using Jetbrains pycharm but the solution for that was every time I had to open it via batch file.

Comment: You need to add lots more detail: how did you install Anaconda: multi-user or single-user? and were you logged in as Administrator or user? and which path did you try to install it to, was it one protected by Windows UAC like C:\PROGRAM FILES and packages under DOCUMENTS? Paths like that can cause tons of grief with UAC.

Comment: Sounds like it's only a path problem; don't say *"it was of no use"* if it successfully installed and showed up in menus and can be opened by clicking from there. Again, you need to say how you're trying to open it (command-line?) and what the symptom is (file not found?). Did you reboot/re-login after modfying environment settings like PATH?

Answer (score 0):

yeah same thing happened to me once
•jupyter notebook can be downloaded from the terminal in windows/Linux.

there are other text editors like **Google Collab** , **Sublime Text3**, **Atom** etc..

they are also good for Python Programming.
•personally i recommend **Google Collab** because it is easy to use, there are no complicated settings like pycharm. Collab is also free to use. U can practice in online and u can download it from terminal of ur OS

• Sublime text is also good u can get free version and premium.

links:
Google Collab
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb
Google Collab Download for win 10
https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/

Sublime Text 3 download
https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Atom Download
https://atom.io/

I tried my Best to answer ur question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need Anaconda for jupyter notebook. You can install it using pip as:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Or:

```
pip install notebook
```

And then use

```
jupyter notebook
```

In command prompt to open.

You can also Visual Studio code or Atom for text editor which I personally found good and much better than spyder.